# Ajax request Select2 - Resultlist always empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I tried using the Select 2 plugin with ajax as data source, but I always receive "No results found" in the result list, after typing some letters. I expected that it would list all found items (Field: LastName) from my Ajax response in my search results. I attached the ajax response at the end of this post.

**My HTML select element:**

```
<select class="player-select form-control">
</select>
```

**My Select2 JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".player-select").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "/database/players.php",
            dataType: "json",
            delay: 250,
            processResults: function (data) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data
                return {
                    results: data.LastName
                };
            }
        },
        minimumInputLength: 1,
    })
});
```

**My AJAX Response:**

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":"27",
      "FirstName":"Joe",
      "LastName":"Cole",
      "CommonName":null,
      "Rating":"72",
      "Position":"14",
      "LastPriceUpdate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"34079",
      "FirstName":"Ashley",
      "LastName":"Cole",
      "CommonName":null,
      "Rating":"77",
      "Position":"14",
      "LastPriceUpdate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"146545",
      "FirstName":"David",
      "LastName":"C\u00f3rcoles Alcaraz",
      "CommonName":"C\u00f3rcoles",
      "Rating":"66",
      "Position":"45",
      "LastPriceUpdate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"171565",
      "FirstName":"Miguel",
      "LastName":"Linares C\u00f3lera",
      "CommonName":"Linares",
      "Rating":"69",
      "Position":"45",
      "LastPriceUpdate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"180216",
      "FirstName":"S\u00e9amus",
      "LastName":"Coleman",
      "CommonName":null,
      "Rating":"81",
      "Position":"25",
      "LastPriceUpdate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"189884",
      "FirstName":"Shannon",
      "LastName":"Cole",
      "CommonName":null,
      "Rating":"63",
      "Position":"195",
      "LastPriceUpdate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"198199",
      "FirstName":"Pablo",
      "LastName":"Alcolea Guerrero",
      "CommonName":"Alcolea",
      "Rating":"63",
      "Position":"45",
      "LastPriceUpdate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"203268",
      "FirstName":"Larnell",
      "LastName":"Cole",
      "CommonName":null,
      "Rating":"63",
      "Position":"14",
      "LastPriceUpdate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   },
   {  
      "Id":"219795",
      "FirstName":"Joel",
      "LastName":"Coleman",
      "CommonName":null,
      "Rating":"56",
      "Position":"14",
      "LastPriceUpdate":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `processResults` method would slightly vary, since you are trying to get a custom result matching `LastName` on each item. I've added comments so that you will know what has to be done.

```
processResults: function(data, params) {
  var resData = [];//just to store matching data
  //iterate through each data
  data.forEach(function(value) {
    //check if the LastName param contains the search param entered
    if (value.LastName.indexOf(params.term) != -1)
      resData.push(value)//push the item to resData array
  })
  return {
    results: $.map(resData, function(item) {
      //now while returning you need to map the array text and id property since you are
      //returning custom query
      return {
        text: item.LastName,
        id: item.Id
      }
    })
  };
},
```

## [`A Full Demo Here`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/t5r65ake/)

Comment: this worked for me. I was also returning a single string rather than text/id in 'results'